# Setar posição Cursor Windows & Linux com mesmo codigo

Tags: c, c++, terminal, prompt, cursor

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação multiplataforma.

Para tal gostaria de desenvolver com o mínimo de "ifdefs" possíveis, e o que preciso fazer é basicamente uma tela fixa de 32 x 16 caracteres.

Porém para que eu possua performance, tenho a necessidade de apenas redesenhar o que se modificar na tela e não toda ela o tempo todo, além disso não ficar dando `system("cls")`, a cada rotina.

Pesquisei e não consegui encontrar nenhuma solução que seja aplicável tanto no *Windows* (*Prompt*) quanto no *Linux* (*Terminal*).

Comment: Sua plataforma alvo tem qual CPU?Algo rodnado a menos que 20MHz? Em tela texto,a não ser que vocẽ queira trabalhar com algumas dezenas de FPS, não vai fazer direferença de performance redesenhar a tela de texto em C. (E não faz sentido ter uma interface de texto com mais que 4 FPS)

Comment: Se quiser uma forma mais sofisticada de fazer interface gráfica no terminal, existe o [*ncurses*](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). Infelizmente ele não é multiplataforma. Entretanto, existe uma alternativa multiplataforma ao *ncurses* chamada *[pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/)*. Eu nunca usei, mas vale a pena dar uma olhada.